# Change position on item in mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm working with Media Queries and trying to move an item (social icons) to the bottom in mobile devices. Top on desktop and bottom on mobile. It also need to be showed in a row in both devices.

I tried with position relative/absolute. In absolute the div disappears. Also tried with reverse but I can't make it work.

Sorry for a lot of code.

Please help a student :)

```css
/* Footer */

.grid_medium {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.grid_medium_footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#footer {
  border-top: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer_logo {
  width: 190px;
  height: 60px;
  background-position: -8px -10px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.footer_columns {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer_columns .column {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.footer_columns .column:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.footer_columns .plus {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.footer_columns .title {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float: left;
}

.footer_columns ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.footer_columns ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer_columns a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #04fbc7;
  s
}

.footer_contact {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.footer_contact table {
  border: none;
}

.footer_contact th,
td {
  border: none;
  line-height: 16px;
}

ul.footer_contact_text {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.footer_contact_text li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
  line-height: 15px;
}

ul.footer_contact_text li:last-child {
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #04fbc7;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.footer_contact .social_icons {
  float: left;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a {
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  ;
  background-position: -16px -729px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_facebook {
  background-position: -72px -728px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_twitter {
  background-position: -166px -730px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_linkedin {
  background-position: -117px -729px;
}

.footer_contact ul.social_icons li a.social_instagram {
  background-position: -16px -728px;
}

.footer_contact a {
  color: #3c273a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_contact">
  <div class="grid_medium_footer">

    <div class="footer_icons">


      <ul class="social_icons">
        <li><a href="#" class="social_instagram bgimgsprite">Instragram</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="social_facebook bgimgsprite">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="social_linkedin bgimgsprite">Linkedin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="social_twitter bgimgsprite">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fixfloat"></div>


    <!--  Kontakt uppgifter statiska -->
    <ul class="footer_contact_text">
      <li>
        <?php echo (get_option('inst_namn')); ?>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php echo (get_option('inst_sidfot_gata')); ?>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php echo (get_option('inst_postnr')); ?>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php echo (get_option('inst_epost')); ?>
      </li>
    </ul><br>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <?php echo (get_option('inst_orgnr')); ?>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>


  </div>
  <!-- grid_medium_footer -->
</div>
<!--footer_contact -->
```

Comment: Can u replace the HTML with php to a version where it's already build? :) Also I don't see any media query?

Comment: Make it easy for yourself. Include the icons both in header and footer. Use *display: none;* in the media query where appropriate.